# Is my 1999 blazer having transmission problems?

Tags: transmission, sparkplugs, fuel-injection, torque-converter, transmission-fluid

I have a '99 Chevy Blazer. It never wants to get moving right away. It takes 30 seconds to a minute before I can get fully going. It also shakes when I am at a red light or stopped.

I noticed today that the transmission fluid smelled bad. I am going to get it flushed.

Do I need:

1. Fuel injector cleaner?
2. Spark plugs?
3. Torque converter?
4. All of the above?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Drain and refill the transmission. That fixes more transmission issues than anything else. Do NOT get a 'transmission flush' (unless your owners manual recommends it... which it won't). If you flush the transmission on a car that old, you're quite likely to dislodge a lot of crud that can cause more damage than you started with. For the others... check the service history.

Answer (score 1):

as PeteCon said do not do a flush

Have the trans drained trans filter cleaned or replaced and then refilled. It may still be low so after filling it they need to check and make sure it is no longer low.

The shaking at a red light might be your trans grabbing and releasing or a belt that is sticking and letting go. Get the trans fluid changed then start on other things.

One thing it could be which a refill will not help and a flush only has a chance of fixing is you could have a port in the trans that is blocked making the first gear bands cylinder very slow.

Comment: Also...make ULTRA sure they do not OVER fill your transmission.

Answer (score 0):

How was the fluid level, do you have the proper amount of fluid in it? If so, then it sounds like it could be the torque converter, but I'd have a mechanic or transmission shop take a look and get their recommendation. Could be all you need is a drain and a refill with the proper fluid. Shaking at a red light could be worn or dirty plugs, the transmission, or something like an engine mount. A good first step would be to pull a couple of the plugs and take a look.